# dt_fill only on specific column

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to fill NAs in some columns of a `data.table`with `dt_fill`. Unfortunately, I get an error message:

```
Fehler in `[.data.table`(dt_, , lapply(.SD, fun), by = eval(by), .SDcols = dots) : 
Some items of .SDcols are not column names: [x]
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's a reproductive code:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyfast)

x = 1:10
dt = data.table(v1 = x,
                v2 = shift(x),
                v3 = shift(x, -1L),
                v4 = sample(c(rep(NA, 10), x), 10),
                grp = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))

cols <- colnames(dt)[2:4]

dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) dt_fill(dt, x, .direction = "down")), .SDcols=cols]
```

Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table::nafill`

```
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type="locf"), .SDcols=cols]
```

Output:

```
       v1    v2    v3    v4   grp
    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1:     1    NA     2     5     2
 2:     2     1     3     9     2
 3:     3     2     4     4     1
 4:     4     3     5     4     2
 5:     5     4     6     4     3
 6:     6     5     7     4     1
 7:     7     6     8     4     3
 8:     8     7     9     1     3
 9:     9     8    10     1     1
10:    10     9    10     1     1
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
dt = data.table(v1 = x,
                v2 = shift(x),
                v3 = shift(x, -1L),
                v4 = sample(c(rep(NA, 10), x), 10),
                grp = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```